# Python Fourier transform of numpy array

Tags: python, signals, fft

I have a problem trying to represent the Fourier transformation of a signal.
This is the my code:

```
path = "./sensor_20170315_140457Z.das.h5"
p5 = h5py.File(path, 'r')
dsData = p5["DAS/Data"]
ds_as_array = np.array(dsData, dtype=np.int32)
channel = ds_as_array[355, 0:2500]
channel_t=np.arange(0,1,0.0004)
plt.plot(channel_t, channel)
plt.show()
```

And my code to calculate the Fourier transform is:

```
Y = fft(y)
plt.plot(Y)
plt.show()
```

and the output is :

[image]

I don't understand this output, how could I know the frequencies?
I also try the sample of the scipy documentation, but the result is even more disappointed

```
N = 2500
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 2500.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = channel
print(y)
yf = fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2]))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

and its output is:

[image]

Comment: Concerning the 2nd plot, it seems that it needs to be zoomed. Try logscale also?

Comment: Thank you, I will try to find the instruction to do a logscale.

Comment: Sure! Maybe it would be useful to add some data as well.Also don't forget units in the plots. Otherwise things will get messy...

Comment: Sorry, but what does it mean the output of the first plot? To be honest I am a bit lost.

Comment: I can provide some Theory of FFT but not combined with Python. So for a given pulse (P=P(t) :time dependent) , via FFT you get the decomposition into frequencies  as in : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GyVj.png. What is you're missing here is the Mathematical Ideas behind FFT and trying to explain it yourself in simple words. Code will be your 2nd task. Don't forget to share some data.